# How to "Resolve All" or bind a key to "Resolve Next" in Sublime Merge?

Tags: sublimemerge

I have a ton of conflicts that I need to resolve, and it would really help if there was a way for me to just decide to "Resolve All", which would queue up all the files that need to be resolved.

Another idea is to bind the "Resolve" button to a key so that I can just click that keybinding to resolve the next conflict.

I've googled around quite a bit, but to no avail.

The ["Key Binding"-documentation](https://www.sublimemerge.com/docs/key_bindings) does not mention this.

Thanks!

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using macOS.

Comment: Hey, I am using macOS too. There's an option in Settings » Keyboard » Shortcuts and you can assign application shortcuts.

Comment: If you're referring to changing or adding key bindings, then - like I wrote in my question - I'm already aware of how to do that. The problem is that there's no documentation on how to bind keys to "Resolve All" or "Resolve Next"

Comment: No I didn't mean that. I was talking about [this](https://i.imgur.com/i3N6XFT.png).

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman: that's of no use, there is no menu or keyboard shortcut for the resolve buttons in Sublime Merge.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ahhhh I get it now. Okay...

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR.

```json
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+super+shift+r"],
        "command": "resolve_merge_conflict", "args": { "path": "$path" },
    },
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+super+shift+t"],
        "command": "stage_file", "args": { "path": "$path" },
    },
```

##### Explanation

The [documentation you mention](https://www.sublimemerge.com/docs/key_bindings#command) explains how to do this:

> Currently there is no compiled list of all built-in commands. The names of many commands can be found by looking at the Default ({PLATFORM_NAME}).sublime-keymap and Main.sublime-menu files in the Default - Merge.sublime-package and Default.sublime-packagepackages. See the [Packages documentation](https://www.sublimemerge.com/docs/packages) for information on where to find the package and view the contents.

The commands you looking for is in `Unmerged File.sublime-menu` under `Default` package: `resolve_merge_conflict` and `stage_file`. They both accept `path` argument.